# EditableGrid loadXML

Tags: php, plsql, editablegrid

I am using EditableGrid's loadXML(URL) or loadJSON(URL) to fetch data from oracle.

I've realized that EditableGrid will generate a GET request with a token ID added to the end of my URL .

So the request url became url&1478799713810

And my server side script will return an error message as follow.

> Missing '=' in query string or post form.

That is because server script, to be more specific, I am using PL/SQL via Apache PL/SQL Gateway instead of PHP.

I guess, php will automatically take care of that token, but pl/SQL's stored procedure won't recognize that extra parameter.

is there a way to stop EditableGrid from adding any extra or is there a way for pl/SQL to ignore or take that extra ampersand and token number?

Answer (score 0):

i added a # at the end of my url, it is a illegal url character which terminates the url, by doing so, my mod pl/sql ignored whatever comes after #.